# Python csv writer won't add my column

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to take data from a csv file do a calculation and add it back to the original file but I have no idea why my python code will not print me out my 'whip' calculation. Here's what I'm working with:

```
import csv 
print('enter Start year ')
startYear = input('start year: ')

print('enter End year ')
endYear = input('end year: ')

with open('Pitching.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    with open('new_stats.csv', 'w') as new_file:
        #headers = csv_reader.next()
        #headers.append("Whip")
        fieldnames = ['playerID', 'yearID', 'stint', 'teamID', 'lgID', 'W', 'L', 'G', 'GS', 'CG', 'SHO', 'SV', 'IPouts', 'H', 'ER', 'HR', 'BB', 'SO', 'BAOpp', 'ERA', 'IBB', 'WP', 'HBP', 'BK', 'BFP', 'GF', 'R', 'SH', 'SF', 'GIDP']           
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)            
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader: 
            currentYear = line['yearID']
            if int(currentYear) >= int(startYear) and int(currentYear) <= int(endYear):         
                walks = line['BB']
                hits = line['H']
                inningsPitched = line['Ipouts']
                innings = inningsPitched/3.0
                add = walks + hits
                whip = add / innings
                whip2 = whip
                line.append(whip2)
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
                #csv_writer.write(line['Whip'])
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to do this with pandas?

Comment: You need to fix your indentation (I'll make an attempt - revise my edit)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this line

```
csv_writer.write(line['Whip'])
```

is that a `csv.DictWriter` object doesn't have a `write()` method. It appears that you are trying to write out your 30 columns of input data with  `csv_writer.writerow(line)` and then somehow *append* another column. But that is not how `DictWriter` works. It expects to get a dict that describes the *entire* line you want it to output, and then it converts that dict to a comma-separated line that it writes to your file. Once the line is written, you can't add to it. By using `csv` you give up direct control over your output file.

So,

Step 1. Specify `Whip` as one of the columns in the output file, by putting it in `fieldnames`.

```
fieldnames = ['playerID', 'yearID', 'stint', 'teamID', 'lgID', 'W', 'L', 'G', 'GS', 'CG', 'SHO', 'SV', 'IPouts', 'H', 'ER', 'HR', 'BB', 'SO', 'BAOpp', 'ERA', 'IBB', 'WP', 'HBP', 'BK', 'BFP', 'GF', 'R', 'SH', 'SF', 'GIDP', 'Whip']
```

(You had something similar in code you subsequently commented out. You were on the right track at that point.)

Step 2. Remember that `line` is a dict, not a list. Add the value of `whip2` using dictionary notation, not `append()`. `line.append(whip2)` will simply fail with `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`.

```
line['Whip'] = whip2
```

Then `csv_writer.writerow(line)` will get a complete dict, *including* your additional column, and the `writerow()` call will write it all out at once.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, it still appears to only print out the Headers and nothing else when I attempt to use the math. With out the math it prints out all the data.

Comment: Then I think you must be getting error messages that you are not paying enough attention to. For example, in your output file you have a column called `IPouts` but your code is calling it `Ipouts`. Are you maybe getting a KeyError?